# Implement Joi in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

Simple joi validation snippet in javascript.It will simply return an error object when validation fails.

**validate.js**

```
const Joi =require("joi");

function validateObject (input) {
const schema = {
    key: Joi.string().required(),
  };
  return Joi.validate(input, schema);
};

let {error} = validateObject({key:5})
console.log(error)
```

Now I am learning typescript and like to do the exact functionality in TS.I am aware that Joi is  a javascript library but can we make use of it in Typescript.When exploring I came across some alternatives like [https://github.com/joiful-ts/joiful](https://github.com/joiful-ts/joiful/issues).

I am curious to know if there is any straightforward approach using **Joi directly in typescript**. Or little bit of changes to make the Joi work exactly like in Javascript.

**WHAT I TRIED**

**validate.ts**

```
import * as Joi from "joi";

export const validateObject = (input: object) => {
const schema = {
    home: Joi.string().required(),
  };
  return Joi.validate(input, schema);
};
validateObject({key:5})
```

While compiling, I got the error

> Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
>
> 703     map(iterable: Iterable<[string | number | boolean | symbol,
> symbol]> | { [key: string]: symbol }): this;

**UPDATE**
**I have installed @types/joi as suggested in the answer but still the same error**

I am basically looking for validating string,boolean,number,array and object keys as it can be done easily with Joi in Javascript

Comment: Can you add your `tsconfig.json` here or any other `tsc` options you might be using? I don't think this is a `joi` problem and is just a configuration problem. Also confirm your `typescript` version.

Comment: What version of joi were you using? Your code works just fine on stackblitz with version 14: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ccvxmy

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please change your import

```
-const Joi =require("joi");
+import Joi from "joi";
```

And make sure you've installed the types by using

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/joi
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this code instead.

```
import * as Joi from "joi";

export const validateObject = (input: object) => {
    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
      home: Joi.string().required(),
    });
  return schema.validate(input);
};
validateObject({key:5})
```

I hope you will manage to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Type definitions for Joi exists: [@types/joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/joi) or [@types/hapi__joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hapi__joi) (for joi version 17).

Add those to your package.json, and you should be able to use Joi with Typescript. Generally speaking you should not be downloading seperate libraries to make a package work in Typescript, some definitions should do

Comment: Yes installed the @types.But when i tried to run the code i got the error ```Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

703 map(iterable: Iterable<[string | number | boolean | symbol, symbol]> | { [key: string]: symbol }): this;```

Comment: I made an npm i @types/joi  .But the above error exists

Comment: How can i make use of Joi after installing @types/joi ? Currently ,i can see @types/joi in my package.json

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `import * as Joi from "joi"` is going to give you much joy. You are importing all exported members with that.

Is there an individual export you are wanting? Use `import { IndividualExport } from "joi"`

Is there a default export you are wanting? Use `import Joi from "joi"`

Also is there a reason you are calling `Joi` in the second example but not the first?

Comment: sorry joi() was a typo

Comment: But i get a different error while compiling, ```Cannot find name 'Iterable'.

703     map(iterable: Iterable<[string | number | boolean | symbol, symbol]> | { [key: string]: symbol }): this;```

Comment: `import joi from 'joi'` should really do the trick. Then use `joi.validate()` as you would normally. Which version are you running? `14.3.1` works fine for me when importing and using via that method. Also, I'm not sure if it would help but maybe try `const schema = joi.object({ key: joi.string().required() })` for your schema?

Answer (score 0):

`Zod` seems to be a popular Joi alternative for TypeScrip:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod