# Extended Joi not implementing custom operators

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, joi

I have issues extending joi class with custom operators. I want to validate mongodb Ids, but the extended object throws following error:

```
error: uncaughtException: JoiObj.string(...).objectId is not a function
TypeError: JoiObj.string(...).objectId is not a function
```

Code is following:

```
import Joi from 'joi';
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';

interface ExtendedStringSchema extends Joi.StringSchema {
    objectId(): this;
}

interface ExtendedJoi extends Joi.Root {
    string(): ExtendedStringSchema;
}

const JoiObj: ExtendedJoi = Joi.extend({
    base: Joi.string(),
    type: 'objectId',
    messages: {
        'objectId.invalid': '"{{#label}}" must be a valid mongo id'
    },
    validate(value, helpers) {
        if (!mongodb.ObjectId.isValid(value)) {
            return helpers.error('objectId.invalid');
        }

        return value;
    }
});

const objIdSchema = JoiObj.object({
    id: JoiObj.string().objectId()
});
```

I found 2 examples:

https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2357

[How to extend a module from npm using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47618273/how-to-extend-a-module-from-npm-using-typescript)

however they use different properties than what is described in TS definition file and thus does not work.

Comment: Which `joi` and `mongodb` version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to extend the `Joi.string()` base. Keep in mind, that you can't validate `new mongodb.ObjectID()` because it is of type `object`. You extended `Joi.string()` and this checks **first** if your value is of type `string`. And it will stop validating if it isn't. You can only validate `new mongodb.ObjectID().toHexString()` which looks like: `"5f91a1449b13e3010c5548a2"`.

This answers is using `joi` 17.2.1 and `mongodb` 3.6.2

```js
import Joi from 'joi';
import * as mongodb from 'mongodb';

interface ExtendedStringSchema extends Joi.StringSchema {
    objectId(): this;
}

interface ExtendedJoi extends Joi.Root {
    string(): ExtendedStringSchema;
}

const stringObjectExtension: Joi.Extension = {
    type: 'string',
    base: Joi.string(),
    messages: {
        'string.objectId': '{{#label}} must be a valid mongo id'
    },
    rules: {
      objectId: {
        validate: (value: any, helpers) => {
          if (!mongodb.ObjectId.isValid(value)) {
              return helpers.error('string.objectId')
          }

          return value;
        }
      }
    }
};

// create extended Joi
const JoiObj: ExtendedJoi = Joi.extend(stringObjectExtension);

// create new mongodb id
const id = new mongodb.ObjectID();

const objIdSchema = JoiObj.object({
    id: JoiObj.string().objectId()
});

// will fail because it won't pass the Joi.string() validation
const data1 = {
  id: id
};
console.log(objIdSchema.validate(data1).error);

// will succeed
const data2 = {
  id: id.toHexString()
};
console.log(objIdSchema.validate(data2).error);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot a1300, I was also missing the rules part even tho I messed with it a bit, the structure was not also correct. This works flawlesly. Thank you!

Comment: extending your solution, you can pass `prepare: (val) => ({ value: val.toHexString ? val.toHexString() : val })` in `stringObjectExtension` object. It will take care of conversion before validation instead of manually converting it in data.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I solved it with this package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-oid

```
const Joi = require('joi-oid')

const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.objectId(),
  name: Joi.string(),
  age: Joi.number().min(18),
})
```

Good luck :)